# What even is a lower and upper triangular matrix in the context of Jacobi method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I cannot understand how the hell L and U works in terms of the Jacobi Method.

\begin{equation}
   x_{n+1} = D^{-1}(b-(L+U)x_n)
\end{equation}

Take this matrix system as an example:

\begin{equation}
   \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
         3 & -1 & 1 \\
         3 & 6  & 2 \\
         3 & 3  & 7
      \end{pmatrix}}_A \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
         x_1 \\
         x_2 \\
         x_3
      \end{pmatrix}}_x = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
         1 \\ 
         0 \\
         4
      \end{pmatrix}}_b
\end{equation}

As I understand lower triangular is
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   3 & 0 & 0 \\
   3 & 3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
as, you know, it is lower.

[embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEduT.png)

and the upper triangular as

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

with the same reason.

but looking at my professors notes, Jacobi Method is applied like this:

\begin{align*}
   x_1^{(n+1)} = \frac{1}{3}(1-(-x_2^{(n)} + x_3^{(n)})) \\
   x_2^{(n+1)} = \frac{1}{6}(0-(3x_1^{(n)} + 2x_3^{(n)})) \\
   x_3^{(n+1)} = \frac{1}{7}(4-(3x_1^{(n)} + 3x_2^{(n)})) \\
\end{align*}

so... according to them, L is (-1,3,3) drawing that matrix...
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -1 & 0 \\
   3 & 0 & 0 \\
   3 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Same question applies to Gauss-Seidel too. $_{n+1} = ^{-1}( − _{n+1} − _n)$ L and U in both of this methods corresponds to some weird triangular matrices.

Comment: @Nothingspecial Okay but what is the difference between "strictly upper triangular" with a "upper triangular" matrix? L is $c$, U is $b$, alright, but what is the reason of the L looking not like a triangle in 3x3 matrix? i might sound dumb because I am on anything related to math.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @amWhy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have switched from using subscripts to index the sequence of vectors (in $x_{n+1} = D^{-1} (b - (L + U) x_n)$, expressing the $(n+1)$st vector $x_{n+1}$ in terms of the $n$th vector $x_n$) to using superscripts to index the sequence of vectors and subscripts to denote the entries of vectors (in the equations that give the entries of the $(n+1)$st vector, now called $x^{(n+1)}$, in terms of the $n$th, now called $x^{(n)}$).

Using your latter notation to write $x^{(n)} = \begin{pmatrix} x^{(n)}_1 \\ x^{(n)}_2 \\ x^{(n)}_3 \end{pmatrix}$, we have, with $L = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $U = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ as you wrote, that
$$
U x^{(n)} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^{(n)}_1 \\ x^{(n)}_2 \\ x^{(n)}_3 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} -x^{(n)}_2 + x^{(n)}_3 \\ 2 x^{(n)}_3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
L x^{(n)} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x^{(n)}_1 \\ x^{(n)}_2 \\ x^{(n)}_3 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 x^{(n)}_1  \\ 3 x^{(n)}_1 + 3 x^{(n)}_2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Looking e.g. at the first entries of $U x^{(n)}$ and $L x^{(n)}$, can you compute the first entry of $b - (L + U) x^{(n)}$, and from the fact that
$$
D = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 7 \end{pmatrix}
$$
see that the first entry of $D^{-1} (b - (L + U) x^{(n)})$ is given by the first of the three formulas you wrote later on?  And also, by looking at the second and third entries of those vectors, see where the second and third equations came from?

Comment: I wish I could kiss you, everything finally clicked. <3

Comment: So for Gauss Seidel method only thing that is changing is $Lx^{(n})$ to $Lx^({n+1})$ right? Might be unrelated to question.

Comment: @Caner-sagopaninsagkolu yes it would be similar. The higher-level general issue is that a simple-looking vector equation expressing $x_{n+1}$ in terms of other inputs, if regarded as a system of scalar equations for each component, can generally involve *every component* of the input vectors in the scalar formula for each component of $x_{n+1}$. Hence the need for keeping careful track of notation.